# Youtube player for xamarin forms

Tags: youtube-api, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

Hi I am trying to create a youtubeview inherited from webview with the support of  **youtube-api** (https://github.com/nishanil/YouTubePlayeriOS/blob/master/Classes/YouTubePlayer.cs.) But the IOS UIWebview in this class returns a string after executing javascript, where as xamarin forms webview don't. Could someone help me achive this so that a single control work in all patforms.

There's no good youtube player outside for xamarin forms, there are different examples individually. Please help me.

Comment: you probably need to create your own custom webview renderer

Comment: Hi @Kris ! Did you solve this issue? Facing the same problem you are describing right now as well

Comment: Nope after that I left that thought

Comment: Did anyone solve this problem?