# Xamarin Forms show Youtube video

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-youtube-api

I have an app that works with Xamarin Forms, I need to add a feature to show a youtube player (play and pause). It will be only for Android users at least for now.

I think that WebView is not an option that works for me because I need to automatically play a video and pass to the next one with no  delay or the minimum possible.

I seach this on SO and Google, but I didn't get a useful to now, for example

- [Xamarin + Android + Binding YouTube video player compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290706/xamarin-android-binding-youtube-video-player-compile-errors)
  I can't even understand how he getted to that code
- [Youtube player for xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444570/youtube-player-for-xamarin-forms) He show a link to github IOS only and nobody answer
- https://blog.nishanil.com/2014/08/14/youtube-android-player-for-xamarin-android/ This apparently works, I didn't try because it's for Xamarin but no Xamarin Forms

Comment: Did you try this one [XPlat.YouTubePlayer](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/XPlat/YouTube.Player/android) ? Or you can implement your own [Xamarin Video Player](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/) with the YT video as source.

Comment: @FabriBertani 
XPlat.YouTubePlayer seems to be for Xamarin, and I don't know how  can it be adapted into Xamarin Forms.

Xamarin Video Player: It can be a great option, let me see and tell you later

Comment: @FabriBertani  Xamarin Video Player works. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

> I think that WebView is not an option that works for me because I need to automatically play a video and pass to the next one with no delay or the minimum possible.

If you want to do this, I suggest you can use com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView to do this. You can follow the steps to create demo.

1. Download the latest YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/).
2. Create a Android Java binding library project.Once the project is created right click “Jars” folder -> Add existing item-> Add the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar,lick on the properties of the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar and mark the BuildAction as “EmbeddedJar”.

3.Create a new Xamarin Android project,reference the Library project we created,add “Internet” permission to the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


 public class MainActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity, IYouTubePlayerOnInitializedListener
{
    private int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    public void OnInitializationFailure(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason)
    {
        if (errorReason.IsUserRecoverableError)
        {
            errorReason.GetErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Format(
                    GetString(Resource.String.ErrorMessage), errorReason.ToString());
            Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
    public void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider p0, IYouTubePlayer yPlayer, bool p2)
    {
        if(!p2)
        {
            //load list video
            yPlayer.CueVideos(DevConstants.list);
        }
         //load single video
        //yPlayer.LoadVideo(DevConstants.VIDEO_ID);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = FindViewById<YouTubePlayerView>(Resource.Id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.Initialize(DevConstants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}

 public static class DevConstants
{
    public static string DEVELOPER_KEY = "your developer key";
    public static string VIDEO_ID = "DHHY8m3rEzU";

    public static List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "DHHY8m3rEzU","luDyX0kYzY4"
    };
}
```

If you still have some issue, please try to add this line in Tramsforms Metadata.xml

```
 <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/class[@name='YouTubeThumbnailView']/method[@name='finalize' and count(parameter)=0]" />
```

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://poojargaonkar.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/playing-youtube-videos-in-xamarin-android-app-part-2/

More feature, you can take a look:

https://blog.nishanil.com/2014/08/14/youtube-android-player-for-xamarin-android/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that I want a solution for Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Sebastian, You can try to use Plugin.Youtube, there is sample you can get from github:https://github.com/HoussemDellai/social-media-templates, more detailed info, please take a look:https://www.thewissen.io/embedding-youtube-feed-xamarin-forms/